# Elastic search IO connection reset by peer

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Elastic Search IO https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java  in order to insert data from Google Cloud Data Flow into elastic search.When I run data flow jobs every thing works normally but after a while I am getting this error :

```
 java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0 (Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read (SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer (IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read (IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read (SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill (SessionInputBufferImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.fillBuffer (AbstractMessageParser.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput (DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:241)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady (InternalIODispatch.java:81)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady (InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady (AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable (BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent (AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents (AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute (AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute (BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run (AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does this specific error cause your entire job to fail, or does the error get retried and the job proceeds?

Comment: The error get retried and the job proceeds (streaming job) since I am catching the error but this leads to data loss

Comment: What makes you think that data loss is happening? Runners automatically retry failures and it is a normal situation that shouldn't lead to data loss.